# c# enum covariance doesn't work

Tags: c#, enums, covariance

I need to use enum as covariant type. Let's say i have this code:

```
public enum EnumColor
{
    Blue = 0,
    Red = 1,
}

public class Car : IColoredObject<EnumColor>
{
    private EnumColor m_Color;
    public EnumColor Color
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Color;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Color = value;
        }
    }

    public Car()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        IndependentClass.DoesItWork( car );
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
public interface IColoredObject<out EnumColorType>
{
    EnumColorType Color
    {
        get;
    }
}

public static class IndependentClass
{
    public static void DoesItWork( object car )
    {
        IColoredObject<object> coloredObject = car as IColoredObject<object>;

        if( coloredObject == null )
            Console.WriteLine( "It doesn't work." );
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "It works." );

            int colorNumber = (int)( coloredObject.Color );

            Console.WriteLine( "Car has got color number " + colorNumber + "." );
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to use Enum.

```
IColoredObject<Enum> coloredObject = car as IColoredObject<Enum>;
```

I was trying to use IConvertible which is interface of Enum.

```
IColoredObject<IConvertible> coloredObject = car as IColoredObject<IConvertible>;
```

But everytime it doesn't work (it was null).

What should i use ? Or how can i do it ?

(I don't want to use EnumColor in second part of code, because i want two independent codes joined only with interface.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Covariance is not supported with "Value types" `Enum` falls under this category and hence doesn't work.

> Variance in generic interfaces is supported for reference types only.
>   Value types do not support variance. For example, `IEnumerable<int>`
>   (IEnumerable(Of Integer) in Visual Basic) cannot be implicitly
>   converted to `IEnumerable<object>` (IEnumerable(Of Object) in Visual
>   Basic), because integers are represented by a value type.

[Source MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx)

Comment: It is correct that the reason is that covariance is not supported with value types. However, it is `EnumColor` above which is a value type. The class `System.Enum` is a reference type. In the above code, if an `IColoredObject<Enum>` was attempted converted into e.g. `IColoredObject<object>`, it *would* work. For that, define `class OtherCar : IColoredObject<Enum>`. Then with an instance called `otherCar`, the code `IColoredObject<object> coloredObject = otherCar as IColoredObject<object>;` or simply `IColoredObject<object> coloredObject = otherCar;` would work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved my problem with generic method. It's few chars more, but it works.

First code:

```
public enum EnumColor
{
    Blue = 0,
    Red = 1,
}

public class Car : IColoredObject<EnumColor>
{
    private EnumColor m_Color;
    public EnumColor Color
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Color;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Color = value;
        }
    }

    public Car()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        IndependentClass.DoesItWork<EnumColor>( car );
    }
}
```

Second code:

```
public interface IColoredObject<EnumColorType>
{
    EnumColorType Color
    {
        get;
    }
}

public static class IndependentClass
{
    public static void DoesItWork<EnumColorType>( object car )
    {
        IColoredObject<EnumColorType> coloredObject = car as IColoredObject<EnumColorType>;

        if( coloredObject == null )
            Console.WriteLine( "It doesn't work." );
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "It works." );

            int colorNumber = (int)( coloredObject.Color as object );

            Console.WriteLine( "Car has got color number " + colorNumber + "." );
        }
    }
}
```